# Trying to strip namespace from XML before validating using Streaming parser (SJSXP)

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation, stax, sjsxp

I'm trying to ignore the namespaces provided in the root element of an XML file, in order to validate against an external schema. Unfortunately, I cannot change some of the items, as this is a heavily intertwined legacy system.

I've read (here on SO) that I should be able to use filters around the input XML, but it doesn't seem to work and feel like I'm missing something. When I run the validation, I get the following error message:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'MY_ROOT_ELEMENT'.

Here's the beginning of the XML file with the namespace info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MY_ROOT_ELEMENT xmlns="http://www.mycompany.net/somename" 
  schemaVersion="2.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.net/somename 
                      myschema.xsd">
    ...
</MY_ROOT_ELEMENT>
```

Here's the accompanying beginning of the schema where MY_ROOT_ELEMENT is defined:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="MY_ROOT_ELEMENT" type="MY_ROOT_ELEMENT"/>
```

The StreamReaderDelegate which is used to ignore the namespace:

```
private static final class NoNamespaceStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {
    NoNamespaceStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public NamespaceContext getNamespaceContext() {
        return super.getNamespaceContext();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNamespaceCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespacePrefix(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return "xsi";
        }

        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if ("xsi".equals(prefix)) {
            return XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And lastly, how the validation is called:

```
// reads from the classpath
XMLStreamReader reader = createReaderFromSource();
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(inputSource.getSchema());
Source readerSource = new StAXSource(new NoNamespaceStreamReaderDelegate(reader));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(readerSource);
```

Comment: If you have to suppress the namespaces to make the document validate against the schema, IT IS NOT A VALID INSTANCE OF THAT SCHEMA. You are almost certainly solving the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for posterity's sake.

Seems like the answer is to set the "IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE" property on the XMLInputFactory to false, and then use the StreamReaderDelegate to make sure the xsi:schemaLocation is ignored. Many wrapper libraries make this part of their API, but for [the default StAX implementation](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/enterprise-java-beans/introducing-the-sun-java-streaming-xml-p.html), you need to set the property.

Once I declared the following, and implemented the Delegate, everything worked like a charm.

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, Boolean.TRUE);
```